# OpenLayers places another marker in the center, when this is not asked

Tags: firebug, openlayers, center, markers

I have built a geocoder to zoom in to where the boundingbox of nominatim specifies it. Also it puts a marker in the center at that point so that the people can see where the street is exactly.

The problem is when you zoom in or out in another after panning the map, it will create another marker again in the center, the marker isn't defined in firebug, it still says there is only one marker and this is the correct in the place of the last geocoder search.

I also logged the geocoder function to see if it is called when you zoom in/out and it isn't.

Here is the geocoder function:

```
 codeAddressLocation: function(address) {    
    // street_number                    huisnummer
    // route                            straatnaam
    // locality                         plaatsnaam
    // administrative_area_level_2      gemeente
    // administrative_area_level_1      provincie
    // country                          land
    // postal_code_prefix               postcode (4 cijfers)
    if (address.length < 10)
        return;
    var site_points = new Array();
    var lon = '';
    var lat = '';
    input = address.replace(" ", "+");
    $.getJSON('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=' + input + '&format=json&addressdetails=1', function(data) {
        if (data != ""  ) {
            var bbox = '';
            $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                bbox = value.boundingbox;
            });
            var point = myLib.transform(bbox[0], bbox[2]);
            var point2 = myLib.transform(bbox[1], bbox[3]);
            if (tbMap.map.layers.length > 2 && tbMap.map.layers[2].CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Layer.Markers") {
                var markerLayer = tbMap.map.layers[2];
                markerLayer.markers = new Array();
                var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,35);
                var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
                var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://clipartist.info/RSS/openclipart.org/2011/May/28-Saturday/squat_marker_purple-555px.png', size, offset);
                markerLayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(tbMap.map.getCenter(),icon));
            } else {
                var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                tbMap.map.addLayer(markers);
                var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,35);
                var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
                var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://clipartist.info/RSS/openclipart.org/2011/May/28-Saturday/squat_marker_purple-555px.png', size, offset);
                markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(tbMap.map.getCenter(),icon));
            }

            // Zet de punten in een array
            site_points.push(point);
            site_points.push(point2);
            // return lonlat;
            var linear_ring = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(site_points);
            tbMap.map.zoomToExtent(linear_ring.getBounds());
        }
    });
}
```

It is called here:

```
$('#autosuggest').click(function() {
  // two options 1) unchecking: remove all coordinateSensitive events
  //             2) checking: add coordinateSensitive events

  if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(".coordinateSensitive").unbind('keyup');
    $(".coordinateSensitive").unbind('blur');
  } else {
    tbGeocoder.codeAddressLocation($("#address").val() + '+' + $("#housenr").val() + '+' + $('#city').val());
    $('.coordinateSensitive').keyup( function() {
        getCoordinates($(this));
    });

    $('.coordinateSensitive').blur( function() {
        getCoordinates($(this));
    });
  }
});
function getCoordinates(field) {
  var input = $("#address").val() + '+' + $("#housenr").val() + '+' + $('#city').val();
  tbGeocoder.codeAddressLocation(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite the marker function into a seperate function:
The glitch was in the part: markerLayer.markers = new Array();

This is what works for me now:

```
var tbGeocoder = {
markers: null,
features: new Array(),

addMarker: function (lat, lng) {
    // Check of er al een marker is
    for (i = 0; i < tbMap.map.layers.length; i++) {
        if (tbMap.map.layers[i].CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Layer.Markers") {
            tbMap.map.layers[i].clearMarkers();
        }
    }

    // Feature aanmaken
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(this.markers, new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat, lng));
    var marker = feature.createMarker();

    // Markerlayer toevoegen en de marker toevoegen
    tbMap.map.addLayer(myLayers.markers);
    var layer = tbMap.map.layers.length - 1;
    tbMap.map.layers[layer].addMarker(marker);
    this.features.push(feature);
},
codeAddressLocation: function (address) {
    if (address.length < 10) return;
    var site_points = new Array();
    var lon = '';
    var lat = '';
    input = address.replace(" ", "+");
    $.getJSON('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=' + input + '&format=json&addressdetails=1', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
            var bbox = '';

            // Haal de boundingbox op
            bbox = data[0].boundingbox;

            // Zet een marker in het midden van de map
            tbGeocoder.addMarker(tbMap.map.getCenter().lon, tbMap.map.getCenter().lat);


            // Maak een boundingbox voor de zoom
            var point = myLib.transform(bbox[0], bbox[2]);
            var point2 = myLib.transform(bbox[1], bbox[3]);

            // Zet de punten in een array
            site_points.push(point);
            site_points.push(point2);

            // Linear ring maken om een in een box te zoomen
            var linear_ring = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(site_points);
            tbMap.map.zoomToExtent(linear_ring.getBounds());
        }
    });
}
};
```